# JavaScript integer coming back as a string

Tags: javascript, string

I'm using binance api and for whatever when I ask for price, the price is coming back as a string. When I convert it to an integer, I lose the decimal places. Why?

```
const Binance = require('node-binance-api');
const binance = new Binance().options({
  APIKEY: 'Yourkey',
  APISECRET: 'YourSecret'
});
//binance.futuresMarkPriceStream( 'BTCUSDT', console.log );
let arr = []
binance.websockets.trades(['BTCUSDT'], (trades) => {
    let {e:eventType, E:eventTime, s:symbol, p:price, q:quantity, m:maker, a:tradeId} = trades;
    //console.info(symbol+" trade update. price: "+price+", quantity: "+quantity+", maker: "+maker);
    console.log(price)
    console.log(typeof(price))
     a3 = parseInt(price, 10)
     console.log(typeof(a3))
     console.log(a3)
    if(arr[1]){
        arr[0] = arr[1]
        arr[1] = price
    }
    if(arr.length < 2){
        arr.push(a3)
    }
    if(arr[0] && arr [1] && arr[0] != arr [1]){
        card(a3)
    }
});
```

Comment: Use parseFloat instead of parseInt

Comment: An "integer" is a whole number, and thus has no decimal places. Consider converting to"float" or you could represent the "integer" dollar amount as "pennies" by multiplying (and round/floor) by 100.

Comment: _"When I convert it to an integer, I lose the decimal places. Why?"_ This just made my day :) Thank you

Comment: Come on now its been years since I was in college.. But I understand my error. An apple is a fruit but an orange is not an apple. I get it.  :)

Answer (score 1):

Because an integer doesnt have decimals. Use parseFloat() instead of parseInt()

Comment: duh.. I should have known this.Thank you.